# Vuejs Arrow Function not triggering second statement

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, arrow-functions

I am using a lambda expression within the methods section of a Vuejs component.

The example is below
I trigger `alertyou()` and get the alert, click okay. Then in the vue developer tools I see `this.activated` becomes `true`.

```
export default {
  name: 'HelloWorld',
  data () {
    return {
      msg: 'Welcome to Your Vue.js App',
      activated: false
    }
  },
  methods: {
      alertme: () => { alert('Clicked'); this.activated = false; },
      alertyou() {
        alert('Alert You');
        this.activated = true
      }
  }
}
```

However, when I click the button that triggers the `alertme` lambda. I get the alert message, click okay. But then this.activated stays true!

What is going on here is this a limitation with lambdas? Can you only trigger one statement per lambda? Or does this have to deal with scope once an alert is fired?

Comment: No, arrow functions are not limited to have only one statement within. Change alert for console.log and test it again - do not use alert, as it is blocking statement.

Comment: @WaldemarIce `alert` will not block anything from being executed. The issue is that using an arrow function binds `this` to the parent scope, which is not the Vue instance. He should define `alertme` as a regular function (or use the shorthand like he has with `alertyou`). He doesn't need to explicitly bind to `this`.

Comment: @thanksd Read above comments. I know where he have problem - with scope. And you are wrong, alert is code blocking statement. If you call it, code execution is literally paused.

Comment: Ups, I was wrong :) But alert is blocking :) One of two blocking nonsenses in JS :) Everything else is non-blocking :)

Comment: @WaldemarIce I see what you mean. Yes, `alert` will pause the script execution. But, after the alert is dismissed the rest of the `alertme` function will get called. I thought you were saying it wouldn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is going on here is this a limitation with lambdas? Can you only trigger one statement per lambda? Or does this have to deal with scope once an alert is fired?

It’s neither.

An arrow function keeps `this` bound to the context it was when the arrow function was created. In this case, `this` is not the vue instance. It’s probably `window`

A function declared on an object using the function keyword (or the ES6 object shorthand style) will normally have `this` bound to the object on which the function is declared.

That’s why you can access `this.activated` on `alertyou` but not `alertme`

You’ll want to use the same syntax as `alertyou`to declare the `alertme` method.

Comment: I get it now, how could I continue to use the arrow function syntax though?

Comment: Why do you want to?

Comment: @christopherclark The bad news is that you simply cannot use arrow functions to define methods on the Vue instance like that. There are a lot of questions on the vue-related SO tags about issues caused by this misunderstanding. Vue, from the get-go does some behind the scenes magic to bind `this` to the Vue instance and it simply does not support arrow functions. Using an arrow function will always bind `this` to the context of the parent scope. In your case, since this appears to be a single file component in node, you are binding `this` to `undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

Change `alertme: () => { alert('Clicked'); this.activated = false; }` to `alertme() { alert('Clicked'); this.activated = false; }`. You can see a working example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/zspr5n9w/)

Comment: A little explanation along with the code would surely help.

Comment: Of course: As @thanksd mentioned above in the comments of the main post, the arrow functions binds `this` to the parent scope which isn't the Vue instance in this case. And because of this you need to use a normal Javascript function which you initialize with `function alertme() { }` or as you can see above with `alertme() { }` which is a ES6 shortcut.